# Formatter Errors and Problems

Tags: java

This is not a specific question, but more of a broad one.  I am using a Formatter to create a file of results outside of java.

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(new File("DataResults2"));
```

For some reason, the things that I am trying to print onto this text file will not appear on DataResults2; however, I can get the things I am trying to print to appear on my console on eclipse.

```
System.out.printf("Market Id %d, Contracts %s, Data Points %d, Starting Date %d,
Ending Date %d\n", firstVariable, set.size(), dataPointCounter, firstDateHolder,    
lastDateHolder);
f.format("%d, %s, %d, %d, %d, ", firstVariable, set.size(),
                    dataPointCounter, firstDateHolder, lastDateHolder);
```

As I stated above, the `System.out.print` will appear on my console however the `f.format` will not appear on my file.

And yes I do close using `f.close();`

What are the issues that occur when using formatter?  Why would a document not show up however the console print everything correctly?

I understand that you cannot answer my question directly without more code, but I cannot show you my entire code before it is too long.  I just want to know some suggestions on what to look for and i will work through my program.  Thank you.

Skeet, does this help at all?

```
 Iterator itr = set.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        { //while
            int contractIDDisplay = (int) itr.next();
            if (contractIDDisplay == 1)
            {
                System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d, %d",contractIDDisplay, monthCounter1, firstDate1, lastDate1);
                f.format("%d, %d, %d, %d, ",contractIDDisplay, monthCounter1, firstDate1, lastDate1);
            }
```

Comment: Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to `.flush()` the formatter?

Comment: I have never heard of .flush(), what is it?

Comment: `Formatter` is buffered; flushing will flush the buffer to the underlying stream (file, console, whatever). `Formatter` implements `Flushable`

Comment: @Danny [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), [`Formatter#flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#flush()), and [`Flushable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Flushable.html) docs for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end you need to call [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). Also specifying the character set would be more portable across computers.

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(new File("DataResults2"), "Windows-1252",
                            Locale.US); // Latin-1 on Windows, US, Part of Europe
Formatter f = new Formatter(new File("DataResults2"), "UTF-8",
                            Locale._US); // International Unicode, US number notation

f.close();
```

---

If that does not work, then use an absolute path for the file, maybe in the user directory with:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "DataResults2.txt";
```

No need to do something like createFile.

Comment: "And yes I do close using f.close();"

Comment: Uh, you call `Windows-1252` portable?

Comment: @fge the application is portable, as on other computer it write the exact same data. Personally I am probably one of the first to use UTF-8.

Comment: @Danny did not want to underestimate the questioner, the relative path can be problemeatci too = different when run in the IDE or stand-alone.